# selenium troubles,AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_selector'

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need someone's  help ! I can't run the following program.How can i fix it?
i'm a new in python.I'm sorry for the inconvenience

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import requests
import os
from PIL import Image
import io
import hashlib

# All in same directory

DRIVER_PATH = 'chromedriver.exe'

def fetch_image_urls(query:str, max_links_to_fetch:int, wd:webdriver, sleep_between_interactions:int=0.5):
def scroll_to_end(wd):
wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(sleep_between_interactions)

    # build the google query
    search_url = "https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&q={q}&oq={q}&gs_l=img"
    
    # load the page
    wd.get(search_url.format(q=query))
    
    image_urls = set()
    image_count = 0
    results_start = 0
    error_clicks = 0
    while (image_count < max_links_to_fetch) & (error_clicks < 30): # error clicks to stop when there are no more results to show by Google Images. You can tune the number
        scroll_to_end(wd)
    
        print('Starting search for Images')
    
        # get all image thumbnail results
        thumbnail_results = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector("img.Q4LuWd")
        number_results = len(thumbnail_results)
        
        print(f"Found: {number_results} search results. Extracting links from {results_start}:{number_results}")
        for img in thumbnail_results[results_start:max_links_to_fetch]:
            # try to click every thumbnail such that we can get the real image behind it
            print("Total Errors till now:", error_clicks)
            try:
                print('Trying to Click the Image')
                img.click()
                time.sleep(sleep_between_interactions)
                print('Image Click Successful!')
            except Exception:
                error_clicks = error_clicks + 1
                print('ERROR: Unable to Click the Image')
                if(results_start < number_results):
                    continue
                else:
                    break
                    
            results_start = results_start + 1
    
            # extract image urls    
            print('Extracting of Image URLs')
            actual_images = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector('img.n3VNCb')
            for actual_image in actual_images:
                if actual_image.get_attribute('src') and 'http' in actual_image.get_attribute('src'):
                    image_urls.add(actual_image.get_attribute('src'))
    
            image_count = len(image_urls)
    
            print('Current Total Image Count:', image_count)
    
            if len(image_urls) >= max_links_to_fetch:
                print(f"Found: {len(image_urls)} image links, done!")
                break
            else:
                load_more_button = wd.find_element_by_css_selector(".mye4qd")
                if load_more_button:
                    wd.execute_script("document.querySelector('.mye4qd').click();")
                        
        results_start = len(thumbnail_results)
    
    return image_urls

def persist_image(folder_path:str,file_name:str,url:str):
try:
image_content = requests.get(url).content

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"ERROR - Could not download {url} - {e}")
    
    try:
        image_file = io.BytesIO(image_content)
        image = Image.open(image_file).convert('RGB')
        folder_path = os.path.join(folder_path,file_name)`your text`
        if os.path.exists(folder_path):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path,hashlib.sha1(image_content).hexdigest()[:10] + '.jpg')
        else:
            os.mkdir(folder_path)
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path,hashlib.sha1(image_content).hexdigest()[:10] + '.jpg')
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
            image.save(f, "JPEG", quality=85)
        print(f"SUCCESS - saved {url} - as {file_path}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"ERROR - Could not save {url} - {e}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
queries = \['apple'\]  #change your set of queries here
for query in queries:
wd.get('https://google.com')
search_box = wd.find_element_by_css_selector('input.gLFyf')
search_box.send_keys(query)
links = fetch_image_urls(query,20,wd) # 200 denotes no. of images you want to download
images_path = './'
for i in links:
persist_image(images_path,query,i)
wd.quit()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj2BC.png)

When i execute the code, I get an error that says

the google's window will jump out but disappeared suddenly.I try many methods but still can't fix the problem.`